# Trigger won' t work when logged with another user sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, triggers, ddl

First of all I am a newbie to ORACLE and I am just working for a school project.

I want to create a trigger that triggers every time someone else than the user named 'ion' performs a DDL command.

When logged on other user, to have access to Ion's tables I used this command:

```
alter session set current_schema = ion;
```

Here is the code:

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t12
    BEFORE CREATE OR DROP OR ALTER ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('LALA');
  IF UPPER(USER) != 'ION' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20022, 'Only Ion can do this');
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO audit_ion VALUES(SYS.LOGIN_USER, SYS.DATABASE_NAME, SYS.SYSEVENT, SYS.DICTIONARY_OBJ_NAME, SYSDATE);
  END IF;
END;
/

alter session set current_schema = ion;

create table dummy(d integer);
```

And it creates the table, and not even LALA is printed, so it means it doesn't even enter the trigger. How can I do this ?

Comment: First of all, I agree with @Littlefoot in that you should _not_ be using a trigger for this.  But I want to point up another misconception you have.  The lack of output from dbms_output does _not_ mean the trigger did no "work".  PL/SQL has no access to the client's display device.  DBMS_OUTPU merely write to a buffer. That buffer is then returned to the client _when the procedure exits_.  It is then up to the client to process - or ignore - that message buffer.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you should actually **REVOKE** all privileges you want to prevent by that trigger.

---

Meanwhile, as of a trigger, you should have probably checked `dictionary_obj_owner` instead of `user`.

I don't have your users (and don't feel like creating that `ion`) so I'm using my own `scott` and `mike`.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> CREATE TABLE audit_ion (
  2      login_user          VARCHAR2(10),
  3      database_name       VARCHAR2(10),
  4      sysevent            VARCHAR2(15),
  5      dictionary_obj_name VARCHAR2(20),
  6      datum               DATE
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t12 BEFORE CREATE OR DROP OR ALTER ON scott.SCHEMA BEGIN
  2      dbms_output.put_line('lala');
  3      --IF upper(user) != 'SCOTT' THEN
  4      IF upper(dictionary_obj_owner) != 'SCOTT' then
  5          raise_application_error(-20022, 'Only Scott can do this');
  6      ELSE
  7          INSERT INTO audit_ion VALUES (
  8              sys.login_user,
  9              sys.database_name,
 10              sys.sysevent,
 11              sys.dictionary_obj_name,
 12              sysdate
 13          );
 14
 15      END IF;
 16  END;
 17  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing (still connected as `scott`):

```
SQL> create table trg_test (a number);

Table created.
```

Altering the session:

```
SQL> alter session set current_schema = mike;

Session altered.

SQL> create table trg_test (a number);
create table trg_test (a number)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20022: Only Scott can do this
ORA-06512: at line 5

    
SQL> alter session set current_schema = scott;

Session altered.

SQL> select * from audit_ion;

LOGIN_USER DATABASE_N SYSEVENT        DICTIONARY_OBJ_NAME  DATUM
---------- ---------- --------------- -------------------- --------
SCOTT      XE         CREATE          TRG_TEST             05.01.22

SQL>
```

Kind of *works*.

Comment: thanks for your help it's more clear now, but the format I have to work with is the following: I need to make a trigger that only lets user ion do the changes and if I log in the database with another user I have to get the error telling me that only ion can make changes. Also, I do not understand why this ```select sys.dictionary_obj_owner from dual;
``` returns me a single row consisting of ```(null)```. What you did works for me, but if I try to log in with the other user the trigger seems to not even exist. Sorry, I am really noob in databases and I really  and would appreciate your help.

Comment: OK. So, did you try code I posted? What did you find out?

Comment: edited now, check it out pls.

Comment: Trigger exists only in schema you created it in, not "globally" - for that, you'd have to use SYS. Anyway, as you were already told several times, that's a **wrong** approach. Simply revoke privileges from users you won't allow to create any objects.

Comment: I trust you about revoking privileges, but unfortunately that is my task for this project, to make a DDL trigger, and the only 'more interesting' one was this, not allowing other users do DDL commands, all the other students did fill the audit table with informations, and that's why I wanted to do something different. But If it worked only on the initial schema, why does this work ok: ```SQL> alter session set current_schema = mike;

Session altered.

SQL> create table trg_test (a number);
create table trg_test (a number)``` ? In these example, aren't we in mike's schema?

Comment: You tell me. If you created the table, query each of those users' USER_TABLES and you'll see who has it, and who does not.

Comment: Thank you mrflex, now I'm gonna fill the audit task just like my mates did, thx.

Comment: You're welcome & good luck!